# Moving cells to another sheet based on a text string using VB (excel)

Tags: vba, excel

Looking for any guidance to help write a VB script

In Excel we have a column containing filenames in Column A

"Y:\master-documentation\allo\dp\abo\tab\100mg\4.packaging\allo-tab-100mg-dp-9-pp-moa-[abo-pr-anl-0685-ver4.0].pdf"
"Y:\master-documentation\allo\dp\abo\tab\100mg\4.packaging\zz-archive\test-form-00mg-dp-xxx-test-[test-file]-01.01.1900.docx"

sheetname=Files

Want to copy to sheetname=Current if string "zz-archive" is not contained in the cell, otherwise move to Sheetname=Archive.

We have used formulas but it will leave empty rows.

Any help greatly appreciated
Thanks
gary

Answer (score 1):

If a formula based solution is still a possibility, then this *array formula* in Current!A2 should work.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Files!$A$2:$A$99,MATCH(0, IF(LEN(Files!$A$2:$A$99),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("zz-archive",Files!$A$2:$A$99)),COUNTIF(A$1:A1,Files!$A$2:$A$99),1),1),0)),"")
```

It needs to be in A2 as a non-involved cell needs to be above it to avoid circular references. As an array formula it requires *Ctrl+Shift+Enter* rather than simply enter. Once entered correctly it can be filled down as necessary to catch all possible returns.

*Addendum:* To use the same formula in Archive!A2, change the `ISERROR` to `ISNUMBER`.

Comment: Thanks, tried it but no output to the cells, I am looking through the formula at the moment.

Comment: @GaryWellock - please see the following sample I worked up on my OneDrive: [Current_Archive_Filenames.xlsx](http://1drv.ms/1zfgWFY)

Comment: Thanks for the formula, I have just learn't what an array formula is. The problem we are having is that the spreadsheet to thousands of rows long and it takes ages to calculate the output, as it needs the result from the previous cell in the row to calculate the next answer. As far as I can work out. Is this correct? Cheers Gary

Comment: @GaryWellock - Yes, *array formulas* eat up calculation resources logarithmically as the size of the cell references expands. You could probably use a filtered copy to update your Current and Archive worksheets. I'll see what I can work up for you on that method. It would probably be best to overwrite any previous results in the two worksheets whenever it is run.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a VBA solution that copies filtered data to each of the Current and Archive worksheets.

```
Sub categorize_filesnames()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsa As Worksheet, wsc As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Files")
    Set wsc = Sheets("Current")
    Set wsa = Sheets("Archive")

    wsa.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
    wsc.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).ClearContents

    With ws.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*zz-archive*"
        .Offset(1, 0).Copy Destination:=wsa.Cells(2, 1)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*zz-archive*"
        .Offset(1, 0).Copy Destination:=wsc.Cells(2, 1)
        .AutoFilter
    End With

    Set wsc = Nothing
    Set wsa = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what we wanted! Works a charm thank you.

Comment: This copies the entire row, was looking to copy the contents of column A of one sheet to column A of another. I am looking up the VB resources on microsoft.com.

Comment: That is sort of hidden within the `.CurrentRegion` definition. Change the two copy lines to `.Columns(1).Offset(1, 0).Copy Destination:=wsa.Cells(2, 1)' with *wsc* in the latter one.